# Python, collect data from an array of dicts

Tags: python

I'm new with Python and I have this structure achieved from a DB

```
data=[
{'Value': '0.2', 'id': 1},
{'Value': '1.2', 'id': 1},
{'Value': '33.34', 'id': 2},
{'Value': '44.3', 'id': 3},
{'Value': '33.23', 'id': 3},
{'Value': '21.1', 'id': 4},
{'Value': '5.33', 'id': 4},
{'Value': '33.3', 'id': 5},
{'Value': '12.2', 'id': 5},
{'Value': '1.22', 'id': 5},
{'Value': '1.23', 'id': 6}
]
```

I know that I can get the id of a record with:

```
data[i]['id']
```

but I need to collect by ID in a proper data structure, in order to get the average values for every ID.

What is the better choice for this?

I'm thinking build a new dict for every ID set, but the IDs can grow in number, and I don't figure out how tackle this problem. If someone can give me some idea I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is sorted by ID as it appears in your `data` variable, you can try using `itertools.groupby`, which can be instructed to group by `id`. You can then create a new dictionary that has keys equal to the `id` numbers and values equal to the `means`:

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: data=[
   ...: {'Value': '0.2', 'id': 1},
   ...: {'Value': '1.2', 'id': 1},
   ...: {'Value': '33.34', 'id': 2},
   ...: {'Value': '44.3', 'id': 3},
   ...: {'Value': '33.23', 'id': 3},
   ...: {'Value': '21.1', 'id': 4},
   ...: {'Value': '5.33', 'id': 4},
   ...: {'Value': '33.3', 'id': 5},
   ...: {'Value': '12.2', 'id': 5},
   ...: {'Value': '1.22', 'id': 5},
   ...: {'Value': '1.23', 'id': 6}
   ...: ]

In [3]: means = {}

In [4]: for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['id']):
   ...:     g = list(g)
   ...:     means[k] = sum(float(x['Value']) for x in g) / len(g)
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [5]: means
Out[5]: 
{1: 0.69999999999999996,
 2: 33.340000000000003,
 3: 38.765000000000001,
 4: 13.215,
 5: 15.573333333333332,
 6: 1.23}
```

Comment: "One obvious way to do it", I guess. :^)

Comment: @DSM Ha, and since I always have trouble spotting the obvious way, nice to have confirmation (especially yours :) ).

Comment: `mean` or `average` might be better names than `dict_by_id`. You could also use `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve the id order.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Good point - variable naming never has been my strong suit. Will update now.

Comment: Naming things is one of hard problems from the famous quote. But (surprisingly) it is shown (for short artificial code examples, in a single study that I know of) that good names help only experienced programmers: a novice programmer reads code equally slow whether it follows good naming convention or not.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That is interesting - was that by chance that study that was released a couple of weeks ago that tracked eye movement as well? I definitely need to brush up my skills in the naming department as I'm sure I've been confusing people who actually know what they are doing for a while now :)

Answer (score 2):

(*Updated:* after DSM's comment.)

You could reshape the data like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data=[
{'Value': '0.2', 'id': 1},
{'Value': '1.2', 'id': 1},
{'Value': '33.34', 'id': 2},
{'Value': '44.3', 'id': 3},
{'Value': '33.23', 'id': 3},
{'Value': '21.1', 'id': 4},
{'Value': '5.33', 'id': 4},
{'Value': '33.3', 'id': 5},
{'Value': '12.2', 'id': 5},
{'Value': '1.22', 'id': 5},
{'Value': '1.23', 'id': 6}
]

newdata = defaultdict(list)
for r in data:
    newdata[r['id']].append(float(r['Value']))
```

This would yield:

```
In [2]: newdata
Out[2]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0.2, 1.2], 2: [33.34], 3: [44.3, 33.23], 4: [21.1, 5.33], 5: [33.3, 12.2, 1.22], 6: [1.23]})
```

(*Update* 2)

Calculating the means is now simple with a dictionary comprehension:

```
mean = {id: sum(values) / len(values) for id, values in newdata.viewitems()}
```

Which gives:

```
In [4]: mean
Out[4]: {1: 0.7, 2: 33.34, 3: 38.765, 4: 13.215, 5: 15.573333333333332, 6: 1.23}
```

Comment: +1.  Two bits, though -- first, you don't need `in newdata.keys():`, `in newdata:` will suffice.  Second, if you use `newdata = collections.defaultdict(list)`, then the `if/else` is unnecessary and you can simply use `newdata[r['id']].append(val)`.

Comment: and to calculate the average: `mean = {id: sum(values) / len(values) for id, values in newdata.viewitems()}`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Good point. I left that out originally because I thought it was rather trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `numpy`, you could use it for this easily:

```
import numpy
numpy.mean([x['id'] for x in data])
```

Otherwise, it would be as simple as:

```
from __future__ import division # if python2.7
ids = [x['id'] for x in data]
print sum(ids)/len(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a list of IDs after all have been collected:

```
id_list = [element['id'] for element in data]
```

From there you can calculate whatever you want.